# docker commands not working with non root user

Tags: docker, docker-compose

while running `docker ps` command receive below error.

`docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/<USER>/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.`

i have already install docker , docker compose.

I already tried adding user in docker group with following command

`sudo groupadd docker sudo usermod -aG docker $USER newgrp docker`

after adding non root user tried docker ps but not working

Comment: resolve above issue with below command
just removing .docker directory

`sudo rm -r  ~/.docker`

Comment: That error implies Docker is pointed at a Docker Desktop socket, but the Docker Desktop application and its Linux VM aren't running.  [This question](/q/73754771) or [this one](/q/73671461) both seem pretty similar, and suggest either a `docker context` command to restore the default or the workaround that @fad1105 suggests.